# How to query api.query.authorityDiscovery.keys?

Tags: polkadot-js, api, javascript

I'm trying to call `api.query.authorityDiscovery.keys` as is described [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#authoritydiscovery) from rpc.polkadot.io like:

```
let current_auth_keys = await api.query.authorityDiscovery.keys();
```

and I keep getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined
```

as if `api.query` does not have `authorityDiscovery` property/object contrary to what is written in the documentation. Could you tell me what am I getting wrong? I'm using:

"@polkadot/api": "^10.1.4"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Polkadot.js API [source code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api) you may access the list of keys from the current authority set using the following code:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

async function main () {
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
  let authorities = await api.call.authorityDiscoveryApi.authorities();
  console.log('authorities: ', authorities.toJSON());
}

main().catch(console.error).finally(() => process.exit());
```

Or just go to https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/js, paste the following, and click the play icon to view the output on the right.

```js
console.log((await api.call.authorityDiscoveryApi.authorities()).toJSON());
```

The previously available function `api.query.authorityDiscovery` appears to have now been removed and replaced with that Runtime call. The [documentation](https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs) is open-source and the Storage section doesn't appear to have been updated yet, but it does include `api.call.authorityDiscoveryApi` in the Runtime section [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/runtime#authoritydiscoveryapi).
For example, if you go to https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/runtime, and choose endpoint `authorityDiscoveryApi` and `authorities()`, then click button 'Submit Runtime call', it will output the list of keys from the current authority set.

Comment: Update: I reported your issue to the maintainer of the Polkadot.js API docs and they replied with a more thorough response here https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/issues/424#issuecomment-1484623983